# NodeJS Redis Client Returning Wrong Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm using the NodeJS Redis client [(Node Redis)](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) and calling the SISMEMBER Redis command. However, when I call the command it always returns true, no matter whether or not the value is a member of the set.

I am using this in conjunction with the [Node IRC](https://github.com/martynsmith/node-irc) module. I am at a loss for why the Redis call is returning the wrong value. I have tried isolating just the Redis code (without the surrounding code) and it works fine. Code follows, thank you for the help.

**This does not work**

```
var redis = require("redis");
var redisClient = redis.createClient();

ircClient.addListener('join', function(channel, who) {
    console.log(redisClient.sismember('visitedUsers', 'awdwf'));
    console.log(who + ' connected');
});
```

**This works, however**

```
var redis = require("redis");
var redisClient = redis.createClient();

console.log(redisClient.sismember('visitedUsers', 'awdwf'));
```

Comment: I doubt if the above code you said is working would actually work if tested with a non-existent user, in which case it should return 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`redis` methods are all asynchronous. The [return values](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/75b0bc97ea3c9b140866fb8fa9888c1aec471943/index.js#L898) are just booleans indicating whether any more commands should be issued for the time being (depending on if the command queue size exceeds the high water mark -- this is similar to node's `stream.write()` returning false).

Try something like this:

```
client.sismember('visitedUsers', 'awdwf', function(err, reply) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(reply);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware they were asynchronous.