# Node.js + Redis memory leak. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, redis, node-redis

```
var redis = require("redis"),
client = redis.createClient();

for(var i =0 ; i < 1000000; i++){
    client.publish('channel_1', 'hello!');
}
```

After the code is executed, the Node process consumes 1.2GB of memory and stays there; GC does not reduce allocated memory. If I simulate 2 million messages or 4x500000, node crashes with memory error.

Node: 0.8.*, tried 4.1.1 later but nothing changed
Redis: 2.8 , works well (1MB allocated memory).

My server will be publishing more than 1 million messages per hour. So this is absolutely not acceptable (process crashing every hour).

updated test

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

var count = 0;
var x;

function loop(){
    count++;
    console.log(count);

    if(count > 2000){
        console.log('cleared');
        clearInterval(x);
    }
    for(var i =0 ; i < 100000; i++){
        client.set('channel_' + i, 'hello!');
    }

}

x = setInterval(loop, 3000);
```

This allocate ~ 50Mb, with peak at 200Mb, and now GC drop memory back to 50Mb

Comment: For a more real world test scenario, I'd suggest you do 10,000 messages, setTimeout for a few seconds to allow garbage collection to do it's thing, then do 10,000 more, etc... and see how that works.  Remember garbage collection does not run while your JS is executing and looking at process memory does not mean that GC has not done it's thing.  Memory reclaimed by a garbage collector is not necessarily returned to the OS, it may just be marked as available for future use within node.js.

Comment: @jfriend00 Good info, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the `node_redis` client source, you'll see that every `send` operation [returns a boolean](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/75b0bc97ea3c9b140866fb8fa9888c1aec471943/index.js#L898) that indicates whether the command queue has passed the high water mark (by default 1000). If you were to log this return value (alternatively, enable `redis.debug_mode`), there is a good possibility that you'll see `false` a lot- an indication that you're sending too more requests than Redis can handle all at once.

If this turns out not to be the case, then the command queue is indeed being cleared regularly which means GC is most likely the issue.

Either way, try jfriend00's suggestion. Sending 1M+ async messages with no delay (so basically all at once) is not a good test. The queue needs time to clear and GC needs time to do its thing.

Sources:
[Backpressure and Unbounded Concurrency](http://engineering.voxer.com/2013/09/16/backpressure-in-nodejs/) & [Node-redis client return values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27586045/1146881)

Comment: By sending 1M at once, redis logs tell me what redis successful handel all messages. However, i made test like @jfriend00 sad

    var redis = require("redis"),
        client = redis.createClient();
     
    var count = 0;
    var x;
    
    function loop(){
     count++;
     console.log(count);
    
     if(count > 2000){
      console.log('cleared');
      clearInterval(x);
     }
     for(var i =0 ; i < 100000; i++){
      client.set('channel_' + i, 'hello!');
     }
     
    }
    
    x = setInterval(loop, 3000);

Now all good.

Comment: @AlexProh Glad to hear you got your memory issues sorted out. Is there any reason why you switched from `publish` to `set` though? Do you have a specific use case or are you just testing Redis performance in general?

Comment: Hoooly cow.... I thought that issue  was with publish method, and replace it with set,  and I forgot to bring back.  Now tested with publish. It's ok. Same result.

Comment: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/870
answer from developer of node_redis